# Side by side short answers in exam environment

Tags: exam

Is there a way to get two short answers side by side? Something like this:

```
Answer A: ___________________  Answer B: ___________________
```

I've tried using tables, but I'd prefer to have only the answers in boxes (which I've not figured out how to do), like so:

```
           ____________________              ____________________
Answer A: |                    |  Answer B: |                    |
           --------------------              --------------------
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Could you add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) with what you've tried so far to give us some of an idea of a starting point.

Comment: Do you mean using the exam class?

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\noindent  Answer A: \hrulefill Answer B: \hrulefill \\

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{3}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{1.0\linewidth}{@{}l |X| l |X|}
  \cline{2-2} \cline{4-4}
  Answer A: & & Answer B: & \\
  \cline{2-2} \cline{4-4}
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here are two macros you can use: `\answerline[<len>]` and `\answerbox[<len>]`. Both take an optional `len`gth argument (default is `10em`):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\answerline}[1][10em]{\rule[-\fboxsep]{#1}{\fboxrule}}
\newcommand{\answerbox}[1][10em]{\fbox{\strut\rule{\dimexpr#1-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}{0pt}}}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% Just for this example

\begin{document}

Answer A: \answerline \quad
Answer B: \answerline

Answer C: \answerline[5em]\quad
Answer D: \answerline[15em]

\hrulefill

Answer A: \answerbox \quad
Answer B: \answerbox

Answer C: \answerbox[5em]\quad
Answer D: \answerbox[15em]

\end{document}
```